# 1/2 gives 0.5, but sqrt(-1) gives DomainError

Tags: julia

This is a question about the design of Julia. In Julia, `1/2` gives `0.5`, and in general integer division returns a Float, so `4/2` is `2.0`. This seems reasonable.

I wonder why the same reasoning was not applied for `sqrt`. That is, to me consistency demands that `sqrt` should *always* return a `Complex`, in particular `sqrt(-1)` should return `im` (or `-im`, but that's another discussion). However, `sqrt(-1)` gives `DomainError`.

Or at least there should be a version of `sqrt` that returns the complex root (just like for division, you have `div` and `/`).

So, two questions:

1. What was the reason between this design decision (inconsistent treatment of `/` vs. `sqrt`)?
2. Is there a version of `sqrt` that returns the complex square root?

Comment: I'm hoping one of the designers of the julia language stop by to answer your first question.

Comment: http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/faq/#why-does-julia-give-a-domainerror-for-certain-seemingly-sensible-operations

Comment: @StefanKarpinski If `sqrt` always returns `Complex`, it would also be type-stable.

Comment: That's true. But it would have awful performance for the very common case of wanting to take the square root of a non-negative float.

Comment: @StefanKarpinski I see. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should read the docs :)

```
sqrt(-1)
```

ERROR: DomainError:sqrt will only return a complex result if called with a complex argument. Try sqrt(complex(x)).
 in sqrt at math.jl:146

So what you acctualy need since im is defined as sqrt(-1) and you need sqrt(-1) you can do this ..

```
 sqrt(complex(im^2))
```

or just :

```
sqrt(complex(-1))
```

Comment: Ok, sorry I missed that. My first question was trivial :D

Answer (score 1):

It actually is in the docs of the [complex numbers](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/complex-and-rational-numbers/):

```
julia> sqrt(-1)
ERROR: DomainError:
sqrt will only return a complex result if called with a complex argument. Try sqrt(complex(x)).
in sqrt at math.jl:146

julia> sqrt(-1 + 0im)
0.0 + 1.0im
```

Or, alternatively:

```
julia> sqrt(complex(-1))
0.0 + 1.0im
```

So in short, in order to get a proper answer for the `sqrt` of a negative number, it has to be of complex type.